# npm pack with symlink to local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've got a project seperated in two npm packages: `front` and `back`. Those packages share code so I created a third package `common` and installed it locally using `npm install ../path/to/common --save`.

This created an entry `"file:../path/to/common"` in my `package.json` file and a symlink to this path in `node_modules/`.

The thing is I use `npm pack` to build a tgz of `back` (which I install in a Docker image). As a matter of fact, the produced tgz keeps the `package.json` as is (with the local reference) but nothing is included in `node_modules/` (ideally, I'd like the content of the symlink to be copied here).

Is there any simple way to pack the tgz archive with all the local dependencies included ?